# semantic ui for angular2 sm-popup margin

Tags: html, css, angular, semantic-ui

I am working on an Angular2 project with ngSemantic. In some places I used semantic's popup (sm-popup). There by default is always a white margin around the border. I need the whole popup to be the same grey color and hence, wanting the white margin (or padding depending on how you see it) to be 0. I searched for two days but got no clue where to configure that. Has anyone encountered similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your css:

```
.ui.popup { border: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Or the component in which you're using it.

```
@Component({
  ...,
  styles: ['.ui.popup { border: 0; padding: 0; }'],
  ...
})
```

Comment: Hi Dan, thanks for you answer, but it doesnt work, there is still that white space at the border. I am using ng semantic so there is no popup class used, instead <sm-popup> element tag is used to create a popup. I also tried to add that css style to that tag and it still does not work. Any clues?

Comment: Hi Dan it works! I was adding it to an angular2 component's css but rather i should add it in a gloobal css file. Now there is a new problem. The arrow on top of the popup is always white while my popup is grey. Do you know how I can change the color of that arrow? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Dan has suggested the answer for removing the white border. So for the arrow part, I guess it will be pretty hard to change the arrow color and hence I changed the variation to basic to completely remove the arrow. It looks pretty good.